# Format Currency Knockout Binding

Tags: knockout.js, bindinghandlers

Can't get my custom bindingHandlers to work. The currency doesn't get formatted on load, but does when you enter a value in the textbox. I need it to format on load.

I am using this tool: [Format Currency](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.currency = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        $(element).formatCurrency({ roundToDecimalPlace: 0 });

        //handle the field changing
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "blur", function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($(element).formatCurrency({ roundToDecimalPlace: 0 }));
        });

    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function () { return value; });
        $(element).formatCurrency({ roundToDecimalPlace: 0 });
    }
};
```

Comment: Please be more specific! Exactly what is not working with your binding handler? Do you get an error? Something unexpected happens, what should happen istead? etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason it doesn't update on load is because you are setting the text and not the value which would be appropriate for a text box (input). Here is what my "update" looks like:

```
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        if($(element).is("input")) {
            $(element).val(value);
        }
        else {
            $(element).text(value);
        }

        $(element).formatCurrency();


    }
```